# Pull to refresh plugin on dataview Ext.js

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, pull-to-refresh

Is it possible to integrate `Ext.js`  pull to refresh plugin  with `Ext.DataView` component ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

There is even a example within Sencha Touch Docs.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-cfg-plugins

Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
    config: {
        plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
                pullRefreshText: 'Pull to refresh...'
            }
        ],

        itemTpl: '<div class="item">{title}</div>',
        store: 'Items'
    }
});
```

Comment: I want it with `Ext.DataView` component not `Ext.dataview.List'

Comment: Well, regarding to the API you should be able to add it to the dataview. What did you try so far?